# Addition to explicit list of items in help centre for legal information?

Tags: feature-request

A legal question pops up about once every two weeks which, from my understanding of the modus operandi of the Ethereum stack exchange, is out-of-scope. In the [Help Center](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), legal questions are not specifically mentioned as off-topic, though the related topic of governance is. Given that almost all questions about the legality and laws of blockchain-related things are jurisdiction-dependent (if they are even defined) and the cross-jurisdictional nature of blockchain, should legal questions be listed as an off-topic subject until such time as there is more guidance and precedent?

Comment: Maybe rephrase the question to ask if legal questions are on topic, and see how community responds?  I agree the site should mainly be technical, but others want a little more scope, and some history, legal, economics seem to be in those areas.

Comment: Changed :) (Also, I don't think the site should necessarily be mainly technical -- it's just that a lot of other topics result in lots of speculation at the moment)

Comment: Thanks for raising the question. It seems no others so far have much opinion on this yet.